# Use firebase auto SDK setup with Webpack

Tags: firebase, npm, webpack, vue.js, firebase-hosting

I am creating a web app that uses Vue webpack with firebase.  I would like to have my firebase credentials automatically change when i use `firebase use <some_alias>` on the firebase cli.  In other projects, this simply meant including the `/__/firebase/init.js` file of firebase hosting.  In this project, I am using the npm firebase library and can load in a specific firebase set of credentials with

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

var config = {
  apiKey: '...',
  authDomain: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...'
}
firebase.initializeApp(config)

export default {
  database: firebase.database,
  storage: firebase.storage,
  auth: firebase.auth
}
```

However, this does not get my credentials based on my current firebase workspace.  Instead, I would like something like

```
import firebase from 'firebase'

const fbcli = require('firebase-tools');

export const getFirebaseInstance = () => {

  return fbcli.setup.web().then(config => {
    firebase.initializeApp(config)

    return firebase
  });
}
```

though synchronous.  Is there any way to synchronously load in my firebase credentials?

Comment: Why do you want this to be synchronous?

Comment: If this function is not synchronous, that's probably because it reads a file internally.

Comment: After looking at the source code, it also do a request to some API, so doing it synchronously is by no way relevant there.

Comment: I want it to be synchronous because my existing code with hardcoded values is already synchronous. Making the module export a promise would require updating every occurrence of using Firebase in a very large codebase that uses it extensively. My second code also initializes the app multiple times, which is undesirable

Comment: also, this data is not fast changing. This seems like something that definitely should be possible in a build step of a project pipeline, as it is fairly easy to write a external script that updates this file before building. But I'd rather not add an unnecessary step to my build

Comment: You may use await/async if you target an environment where they are available. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Otherwise you should refactor your code.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by checking `window.location.host` when in the prod environment and having a production config object if the host was our production hostname and reading from the values of a configuration file otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fs.writeFileSync` as described in this example from [a firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/04/easier-configuration-for-firebase-on-web.html) about reading credentials:

```
const fbcli = require('firebase-tools');
const fs = require('fs');

// by default, uses the current project and logged in user
fbcli.setup.web().then(config => {
  fs.writeFileSync(
    'build/initFirebase.js',
    `firebase.initializeApp(${JSON.stringify(config)});`
  );
});
```